# Changing location of legend and size of bar plot

Tags: pandas, bar-chart, legend

Ive created grouped by data by Age groups and gender and plotted it
But I can`t seem to find a way to change to location of the legend

[image]
This is my code:

`purchase = ds.groupby(['Age','Gender']).Purchase.mean().unstack()`

```
ax = purchase.plot(kind='bar',stacked = False,rot=0, colormap = 'Paired')
plt.title('Purchase mean by Age group and Gender')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] =(6,5)
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html ? You can specify the location with loc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.rcParams["legend.loc"] = 'center right'`

Other options:

The strings 'upper left', 'upper right', 'lower left', 'lower right' place the legend at the corresponding corner of the axes/figure.

The strings 'upper center', 'lower center', 'center left', 'center right' place the legend at the center of the corresponding edge of the axes/figure.

The string 'center' places the legend at the center of the axes/figure.

The string 'best' places the legend at the location, among the nine locations defined so far, with the minimum overlap with other drawn artists. This option can be quite slow for plots with large amounts of data; your plotting speed may benefit from providing a specific location.